# WCF service management

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes, administration

For instance, I have a WCF service that serve clients. Sometimes I should send some commands to that service to get some results. For example, if it's necessary to ban some client I would send some command like "ban John Doe" and service will add user named "John Doe" to ban list. How can I implement that? Should I use named pipes or something like that? Probably I should manage service from machine where service is running. Service is hosted in standalone console application.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with do this with `Code` just you Need to do these step`s:

1. All Client `Notify self` on service(add property to all method as Name or Id)
2. Keep all client name (after first-time) in Static-List  as `ClientList`
3. Write service method to remove `ban Client` From That List
4. Write simple method to check that list and if `client Doesn't exist` in list, simply return none value for any Method

Comment: +1; Except that when you restart your service your list will disappear.  Use a database instead :)

Comment: Probably you didn't understand my question clearly. I know how to make method of keeping client in ban list. I don't know how can I send ban command to service.

Comment: @Merlyn, you right. this is disadvantage! @Kseen, this Issue change your service. in order to do this you must Use `Duplex service`!. ( if you want to call clients for doing some Operation)

Comment: For `Duplex-Services` look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple services that access the same datastore.  One for clients, and one for administration.

*Why?*

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle

*How?*

Use a database, and connect to it from both services.  [Something with a small footprint like SqLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) might work if you don't already have a DB.

*Bindings*:

Named pipes might be a good idea for your binding since they aren't network accessible.  Here is a tutorial:

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

But check out this question before you make the leap:

- [WCF Named Pipe Security and Multiple User Sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033111/wcf-named-pipe-security-and-multiple-user-sessions)

If that seems too risky, you could use net-tcp instead:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_bohansen.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx